# Old MS Office installs haven't updated since 2014

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-office

I have a few old office installs haven't updated in a long time.

Looking at the Office executables, it looks like they were ALL last updated in 2014 (Office versions are 15.0.4420.1017, 15.0.4454.1503, etc.).

For various reasons, I can only fiddle with these machines remotely using the command line. I've tried running the following psexec command, which I've had success with in the past:

`psexec.exe -i -s \\remotecomputer "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Data\ClientUpdateDir\officec2rclient.exe" /update user updatepromptuser=false displaylevel=false`

However, the command returns '-1' and Office is not updated. 
I think that there is a shared problem between these machines, and I think that it is strange that they all haven't been updated since 2014 (all other office installations are up to date so there is a big installation gap between 2014 and 2020). It is not a permissions issue because I have administrative rights.

Any ideas how I can force these office installs to update remotely? Maybe some sort of a patch or update needs to be installed manually in order for normal updates to work...

Additional information:

- All clients are updating from an internal WSUS server.
- All clients are up to date with Windows OS updates; the problem is with Office only.
- All Office 2013 installations are click-to-run (i.e. bypass WSUS).
- The problem Office 2013 installations are old ones from 2014; more recent Office 2013 installations are updating normally.

Log file information:

- I've enabled verbose logging.
- integratedoffice.exe_c2dll*.log, integratedoffice.exe_ruidll*.log, integratedoffice.exe_streamserver*.log are being created sporadically but contain no errors or warnings.
- FireFly*.log is being created sporadically but contains no errors or warnings.
- When I run office2rclient.exe the log *.log is created in %windir%\temp. However, it doesn't seem to contain any useful information.

Example contents of MachineName*.log

```
Timestamp   Process TID Area    Category    EventID Level   Message Correlation
02/13/2020 09:30:10.098 OFFICEC2 (0x1de0)   0x7dc       Click-To-Run Telemetry  aqkhc   Medium  {"MachineID":"d56e358e82cbf8499eb26bb86dae583a","SessionID":"86e1c15b-dc4d-4bf2-bb60-6438a5f30a9e","GeoID":"122","Ver":"0.0.0.0","ExeVer":"15.0.5119.1000","SecuritySessionId":"1","ModulePath":"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Data\ClientUpdateDir\officec2rclient.exe","CommandLine":"/update user updatepromptuser=false displaylevel=false","Bitness":"32","IntegrityLevel":"0x4000"}    
02/13/2020 09:30:10.128 OFFICEC2 (0x1de0)   0x7dc       Click-To-Run Telemetry  aqkhe   Medium  {"MachineID":"d56e358e82cbf8499eb26bb86dae583a","SessionID":"86e1c15b-dc4d-4bf2-bb60-6438a5f30a9e","GeoID":"122","Ver":"0.0.0.0","OSVersion":"6.1","SP":"1","ProductType":"1","ProcessorArch":"0","Locale":"1041"}  
02/13/2020 09:30:11.128 OFFICEC2 (0x1de0)   0x7dc       Click-To-Run Telemetry  amebh   Medium  ClientExe complete. {"MachineID":"d56e358e82cbf8499eb26bb86dae583a","SessionID":"86e1c15b-dc4d-4bf2-bb60-6438a5f30a9e","GeoID":"122","Ver":"0.0.0.0","Action":"1","Result":"-1"}
02/13/2020 09:30:11.128 OFFICEC2 (0x1de0)   0x7dc       Logging Liblet  aqc99   Medium  Logging liblet uninitializing.
```

Comment: Check the logs in `%windir%\temp and %temp% folders`.  Enable verbose logging: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClickToRun\Override /v LogLevel /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f` and restart the Microsoft Office Click-to-Run Service for logging to take effect.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/diagnostic-logs/how-to-enable-office-365-proplus-uls-logging

Comment: Those look like Office MSI build numbers, not Office C2R build numbers. Is that command valid for MSI installations of Office? If they are MSI build numbers then Office updates will come with Windows Updates. Have you checked Windows Updates on these machines?

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for your comments. I checked in %windir%\temp but I don't see anything out of the ordinary (maybe I am looking at the wrong thing). There are recent integratedoffice.exe logs, but the contents are blank. I see no logs indicating that office related updates have attempted to be installed.

Comment: @joeqwerty I am fairly certain that the office installs are click-to-run. On the WSUS server it shows that the clients are updating normally, but there is no record of Office 2013 updates having been installed via WSUS. Also, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun exists in the client registry, which implies that the installation is click-to-run?

Comment: @GregAskew I enabled verbose logging so we'll see what happens.